# Java subclass containing object from another subclass

Tags: java, class, object

So imagine that I have a class A that has 2 subclasses B and C
Can I have as a variable a object B in Class C?

Ex:
Class A
{
....
}
Class B extends A
{
...
}
Class C extends A
{
...
B objectname;
...
}

Comment: Try it and see if it works. (it does)

Comment: Just curious: Why ask before first trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can do it.

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

class C extends A {

    private B b;
}
```